# What is the best way to implement XSLT extension in an Android app

Tags: android, xslt

What is the best way to implement XSLT extension in an Android app.

I want to make something like the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ext:getString('TEST')"/>
```

I tried it already with "Xalan 2.7.1", but that can not be integrated fully into the Android environment.

I hope someone has a suggestion for me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to call a function during the XSLT transformation.
The function is to recharge a particular content.

Comment: _[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318998/how-to-transform-xml-with-xslt-and-display-it-in-android-webview/19402040#19402040)_ will help you.